# create a method that check different object if null throw exception

Tags: java, exception, null

Let's say we have following code:

```
public void a(String a) {
   if (a == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
}

public void b(Queue<Integer> b) {
   if (b == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
}

public void c(Stack<Integer> c) {
   if (c == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
}
```

Is it possible to write a method that do the throw new exception job 
? That is something like this:

```
public void a(String a) {
   check(a);
}

public void b(Queue<Integer> b) {
   check(b);
}

public void c(Stack<Integer> c) {
   check(c);
}
```

Notice that their types of parameter is not the same.

Comment: `void check(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}`
?

Answer (score 1):

you can be more generic like:

```
public void check(Object a) {
   if (a == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly adequate; but note how [Guava's `Preconditions.checkNotNull`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/19.0-rc1/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java/#210) is implemented with generics, to allow you to write something like `this.a = check(a);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <X extends Throwable, T> T ifNullThrow(final T value, @NonNull final Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)
        throws X {
    if (value != null) {
        return value;
    }
    throw exceptionSupplier.get();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).